# Istio ingress-gateway for gRPC (connection closed)

Tags: grpc, kubernetes-ingress, istio, grpc-go, istio-gateway

I have a gRPC server running on k8s cluster (remote server). I try to connect to this service from gRPC client (local pc). To do so, I use Istio ingress gateway. But I get "connection closed" msg with 14 error code.

Here is my **gRPC client**:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("service.example.com:80", grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

c := service.NewServiceClient(conn)

if _, err := c.TestRPC(...); err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error()) // rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection closed
}
```

My **Gateway**:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: grpc
        protocol: GRPC
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

My **VirtualService**:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: service-vs
spec:
  gateways:
    - gateway
  hosts:
    - "service.example.com"
  http:
    - match:
        - port: 80
      route:
        - destination:
            host: service
            port:
              number: 9000
```

My **Service**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service
  labels:
    app: service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      name: grpc
  selector:
    app: service
```

My **Deployment**:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service
  labels:
    app: service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 25%
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: service
          image: registry.example.com/user/service:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: grpc
              containerPort: 9000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: private-registry-secret
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

p.s.

- My example.com is under CloudFlare.
- I have set DNA A record for service.example.com
- There are no firewall rules.
- gRPC connection is on (I think it is not important as it only work for 443 port)

Comment: it is SUPER important your service to have the port name `grpc`. Are you covering this?

Comment: @suren Sorry, I don't understand your comment. As you can see in my code I use "grpc" name for my port because it is required by Istio.

Comment: not in the `Deployment`. In the `Service`.

Comment: @suren Ok, I see. I have forgot to add **service** configuration to my SO post. You can check it now. There is a port with "grpc" name.

Comment: yes! that name needs to be set.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found where is wrong obvious, I guess the host of `VirtualService` should be a DNS in Kubernetes internal. like `service.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: If so, what URL I should provider while connecting to k8s cluster?

Comment: @Klimbo It's format is `SeviceName.NameSpace.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: How I will be able to connect to sevice.default.svc.cluster.local from outside k8s cluster (from my laptop)? That url is internal, not external

Comment: @Klimbo Just read my comment, the DNS is for VS to proxy, not for you to access, you only need to access your host `"service.example.com:80"`